# Linux C++ project directory layout - CMake

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I would like to use some standard layout for my linux c++ project which is built using cmake and contains some executables and a library that these execs might link to.  Currently I just had a folder for the project and a sub folder for each sub project. With a CMakeLists in the top level and one in each sub level that the opt level adds.

```
 Project-
            executable1
            executable2
            library
```

However I think it would be better setup like the following

```
Project -
    lib //Library output folder
    bin //Executable output folder
    src //Al cpp source files
    include //All header files
    test //All tests
```

I would have just one CMakeLists in top level.
I can easily set this up in cmake.  does anyone have reasons for choosing a different layout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't put the lib, bin and test output directly on the project directory: if you want to make a debug and a release build, you get stuck, because you have only one placeholder. Out of source build is your friend! I would use something like:

```
Project
     src
     include
     CMakeLists.txt
```

These will be generated when using cmake:

```
Project_build_dbg
     bin
     lib
     test

Project_build_release
     bin
     lib
     test
```

Comment: +1 for out of source builds. Doesn't clutter your source dir, doesn't require you to edit your VCS' ignore files, allows you to zip your source dir without yielding an xxx mb zip because it contains object files, etc etc.

Comment: Great idea, need to work out how to have two different build types now.

Answer (score 1):

The layout you are proposing to use is pretty much how most of the projects are organised. And its a very well organised way of having a project. I usually also have a `docs` folder wherein goes all the documentation about the project. So heres my usual project setup.

```
Project -
    lib //Library output folder
    bin //Executable output folder
    src //All cpp source files
    include //All header files
    test //All tests
    docs //All project documentation   ------> new addition
```

Comment: +1 docs, I forgot ,thanks.  Will also mean they fall under version control with my git setup.  However as above I will move lib/bin/test outside the project source.